# Jupyter Notebooks Python Modules Not Found

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run some modules in Jupyter Notebooks using different libraries but I always get a No Module error, but when I check pip list, the module is there. How do I fix this?

[image]

Pip List:

[image]

Python Version Output:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

on your terminal -

`python --version`

on your jupyter notebook

`import sys`
`sys.version`

Do they match?

Okay next step:

on your terminal

`which jupyter`

again on your terminal

`pip -V`

See if they running in the same environment.
Post the output if you aren't able to make sense of it

Comment: I can see, they are not running on the same environment.

Comment: this means you have started your jupyter notebook from a different environment (i think python 3.6 ?) compared to where your matplotlib is installed (python 2.7)

The solution is to either start jupyter notebook from same environment or to install matplotlib in the environment where you are starting jupyter

```pip3 install matplotlib``` might work but i can't be sure because i don't know how your environments are setup

On a side note - please explore using virtual environments for your python projects http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Answer (score 0):

I think you have used different kernal/env to run this ipynb. So you can check it by typing `!pip list` to check if `matplotlib` is in it. 
If not you can install it on this env, or switch your env.

Comment: I just checked it, it's also there and there's no activated environment when I installed the modules

Comment: Can you import `matplotlib` in python(opened in shell)?